# Getting element from Multidimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to extract `$t` in each entry array, codes are as follows

```
$myarray=Array(
            [feed] => Array
                (
                    [updated] => Array
                        (
                            [$t] => 2015-07-01T14:35:54.224+03:00
                        )

                    [entry] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [title] => Array
                                            (
                                                [type] => text
                                                [$t] => MAKAMU WA RAIS DKT.
                                            )
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [title] => Array
                                            (
                                                [type] => text
                                                [$t] => AAGANA NIA, ANAYE WAKE
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                )
```

how can i get $t in each entry array..

I dont know $t values, in short, i am trying to scrap blog by blogger. Values in $t are Post Titles. i want to get titles like:

MAKAMU WA RAIS DKT.
AAGANA NIA, ANAYE WAKE

Sorry i didn't explain this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: I updated my answer after your explanation - see if the second part of it is what you intended to get.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't know what `$t` is and all you care is the value like `MAKAMU WA RAIS DKT.`, you can find it this way (get always second value in subarray converted from associative to numeric by `array_values` function):

```
$v = array_values($myarray['feed']['entry'][1]['title']);
$t = $v[1];
```

You can loop over them like this:

```
foreach($myarray['feed']['entry'] as $k=>$a){
    $v = array_values($a['title']);
    $t = $v[1];
}
```

Comment: I doubt he knows what the values are and in which level of the array they are. If he'd know that, all he would have to do is access them using e.g. `$myarray['feed']['entry'][0]['title']['$t']` instead of using `array_search`

Comment: You are about to solve it completely, one problem, how can i iterate to all titles so that $myarray['feed']['entry'][/*be dynamic*/]['title']['t'] for example can be 0 then 1 then 2 to exact number these titles are.. if they are 20 then they will all be echoed..i dont know exactly how many they are because i am fetching from different blogs, some have 4, some have 10 and so on... Only that!..

Comment: @MrAfricaPepya OK, check my edited answer - I added the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using recursion:

```
function extractT($arr, &$extracted = array()) {
    foreach($arr as $entry) {
        if(isset($entry['$t']))
            $extracted[] = $entry['$t'];
        elseif(is_array($entry))
            extractT($entry, $extracted);
    }
    return $extracted;
}

$ts = extractT($myarray);
```

`$ts` will contain all your `$t`-entries

Comment: '$extracted[]' creates another array with only index and values, how can key be stored so i can access key value directly?

Comment: Please be more specific, I don't know what you mean. `$extracted[]` does not create a new array, but is used to push values into the array.

Comment: You are correct, can you fix extractT() function above so that array keys can also be availabe..

Comment: Which array keys do you mean? Give me an example, please.

Comment: Thanks, i think i can use these results.. when i print_r($ts); i get results as shown here http://tanzaniablogs.ga/extract/